# What would cause nVidia to produce this error when I run minecraft with HD textures?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, java, minecraft

I am hoping there is someone who has any idea what this error is all about.

[image: Minecraft crashing]

I am trying to use a 128x texture pack. Specifically SphaxPureBDcraft 128x. I can use the base 128x resource pack with no problem at all. However when I add mod patches to the mix the game gives me this error.

`Your hardware configuration does not meet the minimum specifications needed to run the application. The application must close.`

`Error code:6`

The problem is I have no idea what it is talking about. My computer specs are as followed;

- Intel Core-i7 4820k
- 32GB Corsair Vengance DDR3 Memory @1600mhz
- Asus ROG Rampage IV Extreme
- LSI Megaraid 9260-8i server raid controller
- 4 1TB WD Caviar black 7.2k HDDs
- 2 Nvidia GTX 660 GPUs w/ 2GB ea. (in SLI mode, running in surround
  mode)
- Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit (also tried it with 8 pro still no luck)

So what the heck is talking about?

Things I have checked;

- Java is updated (JDK 7 update 55)
- Updated LWJGL libraries (v2.9.1)
- Installed brand new Nvidia GPU driver
- Tried running on Windows 8 Pro (I don't know why...)
- Reinstalling Minecraft
- Reinstalling Minecraft Forge
- Recreating the texture pack from scratch

Things I have not done;

Ask the good people of SuperUser <----- here right now

So any ideas?

I can provide any info as needed.

Oh yeah it might be good to know, I can run the 64x texture pack just fine. Its just the 128x pack. But I was always able to run it in the past on older machines.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try disabling the OpenGL option under video settings. I don't recall this being a requirement for higher end texture packs.

Also, I've always found Optifine to be useful with higher end texture packs. https://optifine.net/home Improves framerate and allows for more tweaks to the video settings.

Comment: yeah I used optifine and as of right now everything is running better. I think I just need to play the waiting game and let Mojang catch up with the rendering engine to solve the issue 100%.